# Positioning images from left to right using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have div with some images in it. This is my html code:

```
<div id="slide-menu-list" class="row">
    <a href="home.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/icon_menu1a.png" /></a>
    <a><img class="img-responsive" src="img/icon_menu2a.png" /></a>
    <a><img class="img-responsive" src="img/icon_menu3a.png" /></a>
    <a><img class="img-responsive" src="img/icon_menu4a.png" /></a>
    <a><img class="img-responsive" src="img/icon_menu5a.png" /></a>
</div>
```

And here the css:

```
#slide-menu-list{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0px; 
   left:0px;
}
```

But the images are stacking from top to bottom. How can I make the images stack from left to right using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pull-left class ,and specify width for your images

following code

```
    <div id="slide-menu-list" class="row">
        <a href="home.html"><img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="/Capture.PNG" /></a>
        <a><img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="/Capture.PNG" /></a>
        <a><img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="/Capture.PNG" /></a>
        <a><img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="/Capture.PNG" /></a>
        <a><img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="/Capture.PNG" /></a>
    </div>

    <style>
    img
    {
         width:20%;
    }

    #slide-menu-list
    {
         position:fixed;
    }
    </style>
```

if you want that your images be fixed in your page please use affix bootstrap in complex solution
[Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add width:100%; in #slide-menu-list div

```
#slide-menu-list{
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
}
```

and then

```
#slide-menu-list a img{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
```